# When to use Exceptions vs Error Objects vs just plain false/null

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors, coding-standards

I'm in the process of writing a plugin and I'm trying to gauge when to use different approaches of handling errors.

There are three methods I'm considering:

- Throwing an Exception (custom class)
- Returning an Error Object (extension of WP_Error)
- Just return null/false

Some situations that I'm considering

- Trying to get/set an option stored in the Registry that doesn't exist
- Passing an invalid value to a method (which should be rare)
- Calling a method that the class' overloader cannot resolve to

Suggestions? Since writing a WordPress plugin has some special considerations, I'm not sure whether it would be worth asking this on a general PHP board.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's impossible to give a definitive answer here, because choices like this are personal preference.

Consider that what follows is *my* approach, and I have no presumption it is *the right* one.

What I can say for sure is that you should avoid your third option:

> Just return null/false

This is bad under different aspect:

- return type consinstency
- makes functions harder to unit test
- force conditional check on return type (`if (! is_null($thing))...`) making code harder to read

I, more than often, use OOP to code plugins, and my object methods often throw exception when something goes wrong.

Doing that, I:

- accomplish return type consinstency
- make the code simple to unit test
- don't need conditional check on the returned type

However, throwing exceptions in a WordPress plugin, means that nothing will *catch* them, ending up in a fatal error that is absolutely **not** desirable, expecially in production.

To avoid this issue, I normally have a "main routine" located in main plugin file, that I wrap in a `try` / `catch` block. This gives me the chance to catch the exception in production and prevent the fatal error.

A rough example of a class:

```
# myplugin/src/Foo.php

namespace MyPlugin;

class Foo {

  /**
   * @return bool
   */
  public function doSomething() {
     if ( ! get_option('my_plugin_everything_ok') ) {
        throw new SomethingWentWrongException('Something went wrong.');
     }

     // stuff here...

     return true;
  }
}
```

and using it from main plugin file:

```
# myplugin/main-plugin-file.php

namespace MyPlugin;

function initialize() {

   try {

       $foo = new Foo();
       $foo->doSomething();      

   } catch(SomethingWentWrongException $e) {

       // on debug is better to notice when bad things happen
       if (defined('WP_DEBUG') && WP_DEBUG) {
          throw $e;
       }

       // on production just fire an action, making exception accessible e.g. for logging
       do_action('my_plugin_error_shit_happened', $e);
   }
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'MyPlugin\\initialize');
```

Of course, in real world you may throw and catch different kinds of exception and behave differently according to the exception, but this should give you a direction.

Another option I often use (and you don't mentioned) is to return objects that contain a flag to verify if no error happen, but keeping the return type consistency.

This is a rough example of an object like that:

```
namespace MyPlugin;

class Options {

   private $options = [];
   private $ok = false;

   public function __construct($key)
   {
      $options = is_string($key) ? get_option($key) : false;
      if (is_array($options) && $options) {
         $this->options = $options;
         $this->ok = true;
      }
   }

   public function isOk()
   {
     return $this->ok;
   }
}
```

Now, from any place in your plugin, you can do:

```
/**
 * @return MyPlugin\Options
 */
function my_plugin_get_options() {
  return new MyPlugin\Options('my_plugin_options');
}

$options = my_plugin_get_options();
if ($options->isOk()) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Note how `my_plugin_get_options()` above always returns an instance of `Options` class, in this way you can always pass the return value around, and even inject it to other objects that use type-hint with now worries that the type is different.

If the function had returned `null` / `false` in case of error, before passing it around you had been forced to check if returned value is valid.

At same time, you have a clearly way to understand is something is wrong with the option instance.

This is a good solution in case the error is something that can be easily recovered, using defaults or whatever fits.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @gmazzap is quite exhaustive.

Just to add a tiny bit to it:
Consider an application with a registration form. Lets say you have a function which you use to validate the username submitted by the users.
Now the supplied username may fail validation for a number of reasons, so returning just `false` isn't going to help the user much in letting them know what went wrong.
The better choice, in this case, would be to use WP_Error and to add error codes for each failed validation.

Compare this:

```
function validate_username( $username ) {
    
    //No empty usernames
    if ( empty( $username ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Check for spaces
    if ( strpos( $username, ' ' ) !== false ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for length
    if ( strlen( $username ) < 8 ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for length
    if ( ( strtolower( $username ) == $username ) || strtoupper( $username ) == $username ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Everything is fine
    return true;
}
```

with this:

```
function validate_username( $username ) {
    
    //No empty usernames
    if ( empty( $username ) ) {
        $error->add( 'empty', 'Username can not be blank' );
    }
    
    // Check for spaces
    if ( strpos( $username, ' ' ) !== false ) {
        $error->add( 'spaces', 'Username can not contain spaces ' );
    }

    // Check for length
    if ( strlen( $username ) < 8 ) {
        $error->add( 'short', 'Username should be at least 8 characters long ' );
    }

    // Check for length
    if ( ( strtolower( $username ) == $username ) || strtoupper( $username ) == $username ) ) {
        $error->add( 'case', 'Username should contain a mix of uppercase and lowercase characters ' );
    }

    // Send the result
    if ( empty( $error->get_error_codes() ) ) {
        return $error;
    }

    // Everything is fine
    return true;
}
```

The first version gives the user absolutely no clue about what was wrong with the username they chose.
The second version adds description to errors, helping the user a lot.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: By removing the return in the statements, every statement is checked - no just the first one. You shouldn't continue after the first check, otherwise you will end up with all possible error messages as a result of an error.

Instead, return an instance of WP_Error in each check.

Comment: @PeterPetrov You are right and that's the approach I usually follow. However, I have also seen a lot of applications where that return all validations being violated during the submission. This often makes sense in cases the form has a LOT of validation rules and/or form has a large number of fields. The idea is to prevent users from getting frustrated seeing a new validation error after each submissions.

Comment: ah, in that case you're correct. To reduce frustration it makes sense, yes.